# Auto generated column is not refreshed in the DataRow

Tags: c#, sql-server, ado.net

One of the columns, called `ID` my SQL Server database is auto generated. When I insert a new row(s) using `SqlDataAdapter.Update(table)` and accept the changes `SqlDataAdapter.AcceptChanges()`, the `ID` column in `table` is set to `-1`, instead of new auto generated `ID` value. Database insertion work and new rows(s) are inserted into database with sequential auto generated `ID`values.

How do I force `SqlDataAdapter` or `SqlDataTable` to get back correct `ID` values ?

Comment: consider posting the relevant code section.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the issue. For future reference

```
operationDBAdapter.InsertCommand.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Operations(operationType,agentID,resetTime,description,enabled,logLevel) VALUES
 (@operationType,@agentID,@resetTime,@description,@enabled,@logLevel); 
**SELECT ID,operationType,agentID,resetTime,description,enabled,logLevel
 FROM Operations WHERE (ID = SCOPE_IDENTITY())**"
```

After the insertion command, just select rows from the same table.